# How do I allocate/split folders optimally to fit on the minimum number of DVDs?

Tags: windows-7

I need a wayto automatically allocate/split selected folders so that each class of folders take the closest value to 4.7 GB (a single layer DVD-R or DVD+R). While doing this, **files must remain intact** (i.e. no archiving / compressing). I always do this manually and it takes some time, so I want to make this work automated.

For example, I have 4 main folders to be recorded on DVD. Since each folder is greater than 4.7 GB, I need to allocate/split the data. The first DVD should contain the data from folder 1, the second DVD should contain the remaining data from folder 1, and folder 2, so and so forth. The folder structure is as follows:

```
 C:\Users\VAIO\Documents\Downloads\Flix directory

24.04.2011  16:13    <DIR>          .
24.04.2011  16:13    <DIR>          ..
19.04.2011  20:53    <DIR>          Afterdark Horrorfest 1 (2006)
22.04.2011  19:30    <DIR>          Afterdark Horrorfest 2 (2007)
22.04.2011  20:50    <DIR>          Afterdark Horrorfest 3 (2009)
22.04.2011  21:08    <DIR>          Afterdark Horrorfest 4 (2010)
               0 Files                0 bytes

 C:\Users\VAIO\Documents\Downloads\Flix\Afterdark Horrorfest 1 (2006) directory

19.04.2011  20:53    <DIR>          .
19.04.2011  20:53    <DIR>          ..
22.04.2011  19:04    <DIR>          Bonus Films
31.03.2011  02:56       734.021.632 Dark Ride.avi
01.12.2007  22:44            66.005 Dark Ride.srt
31.03.2011  03:23       733.964.288 Penny Dreadful.avi
29.03.2009  20:25            38.382 Penny Dreadful.srt
28.03.2011  19:58       734.451.712 Reincarnation [Rinne].avi
01.04.2007  04:36            35.204 Reincarnation [Rinne].srt
31.03.2011  03:11       733.962.240 The Abandoned.avi
13.07.2007  11:03            34.776 The Abandoned.srt
31.03.2011  03:42       734.060.544 The Gravedancers.avi
15.05.2007  01:43            65.682 The Gravedancers.srt
31.03.2011  03:40       733.771.776 The Hamiltons.avi
18.04.2007  13:41            57.911 The Hamiltons.srt
31.03.2011  03:27       733.796.352 Unrest.avi
13.12.2007  23:48            64.953 Unrest.srt
31.03.2011  04:48       734.023.680 Wicked Little Things.avi
30.03.2007  10:43            54.280 Wicked Little Things.srt
              16 Files    5.872.469.417 bytes

 C:\Users\VAIO\Documents\Downloads\Flix\Afterdark Horrorfest 1 (2006)\Bonus Films directory

22.04.2011  19:04    <DIR>          .
22.04.2011  19:04    <DIR>          ..
31.03.2011  02:38       733.681.664 Snoop Dogg's Hood Of Horror.avi
31.03.2011  03:11       734.988.288 The Tripper.avi
22.04.2011  19:04            66.930 The Tripper.srt
               3 Files    1.468.736.882 bytes

 C:\Users\VAIO\Documents\Downloads\Flix\Afterdark Horrorfest 2 (2007) directory

22.04.2011  19:30    <DIR>          .
22.04.2011  19:30    <DIR>          ..
31.03.2011  02:39     1.208.679.904 Borderland.avi
22.06.2008  20:12            60.542 Borderland.srt
31.03.2011  02:35       918.118.814 Crazy Eights.avi
10.07.2008  11:20            46.967 Crazy Eights.srt
31.03.2011  02:23     1.002.540.838 Deaths of Ian Stone.avi
30.03.2008  01:20            50.463 Deaths of Ian Stone.srt
31.03.2011  02:25       735.291.392 Frontier(s).avi
03.05.2009  13:31            50.671 Frontier(s).srt
31.03.2011  02:21     1.040.078.558 Lake Dead.avi
07.06.2008  16:41            65.426 Lake Dead.srt
31.03.2011  02:19       967.749.014 Mulberry Street.avi
07.09.2008  22:26            42.844 Mulberry Street.srt
31.03.2011  02:19     1.027.922.590 Nightmare Man.avi
21.03.2008  17:50            64.914 Nightmare Man.srt
31.03.2011  02:22     1.082.145.354 Tooth and Nail.avi
23.09.2010  07:09            52.948 Tooth and Nail.srt
31.03.2011  02:11     1.072.503.132 Unearthed.avi
22.09.2010  10:45            48.445 Unearthed.srt
              18 Files    9.055.512.816 bytes

 C:\Users\VAIO\Documents\Downloads\Flix\Afterdark Horrorfest 3 (2009) directory

22.04.2011  20:50    <DIR>          .
22.04.2011  20:50    <DIR>          ..
31.03.2011  01:33       729.964.544 Autopsy.avi
22.03.2009  10:25            54.802 Autopsy.srt
31.03.2011  01:39       734.175.232 Butterfly Effect 3 Revelations.avi
25.03.2009  22:39            77.339 Butterfly Effect 3 Revelations.srt
31.03.2011  01:48       730.834.944 Du Saram Yida (voices).avi
11.04.2009  01:45            45.309 Du Saram Yida (voices).srt
31.03.2011  01:33       733.937.664 Dying Breed.avi
13.01.2010  13:12            59.939 Dying Breed.srt
31.03.2011  01:24       729.972.736 From Within.avi
23.03.2009  21:19            65.722 From Within.srt
31.03.2011  02:19       724.623.360 Perkins 14.avi
27.03.2009  20:34            65.208 Perkins 14.srt
31.03.2011  01:19       725.004.288 Slaughter.avi
30.03.2009  00:00            49.874 Slaughter.srt
31.03.2011  01:31       731.213.824 The Broken.avi
22.03.2009  20:55            31.715 The Broken.srt
              16 Files    5.840.176.500 bytes

 C:\Users\VAIO\Documents\Downloads\Flix\Afterdark Horrorfest 4 (2010) directory

22.04.2011  21:08    <DIR>          .
22.04.2011  21:08    <DIR>          ..
31.03.2011  04:37     1.558.781.952 Dread.avi
03.04.2010  15:47            49.730 Dread.srt
31.03.2011  04:48       793.290.092 Hidden (Skjult).avi
16.04.2010  20:40            21.836 Hidden (Skjult).srt
31.03.2011  04:48       734.856.572 Kill Theory.avi
06.12.2009  11:59            58.779 Kill Theory.srt
31.03.2011  04:47       734.552.064 Lake Mungo.avi
01.04.2010  09:40            76.751 Lake Mungo.srt
31.03.2011  04:27       735.004.672 The Final.avi
28.03.2010  11:28            59.547 The Final.srt
31.03.2011  04:48       734.115.840 The Graves.avi
03.04.2010  15:31            60.854 The Graves.srt
31.03.2011  03:49       733.177.856 The Reeds.avi
28.03.2010  13:36            50.100 The Reeds.srt
31.03.2011  04:48       735.211.520 Zombies of Mass Destruction.avi
01.04.2010  20:47            71.634 Zombies of Mass Destruction.srt
              16 Files    6.759.439.799 bytes

     Listed Total Files:
              70 Files      28.996.335.414 bytes
              17 Directories    77.467.275.264 bytes free
```

I need to allocate/split the folders so that I can use minimum number of blank DVDs and make sure maximum data are written on each DVD. There is a total of 29 GB data.

Is there any method of doing this in Windows 7?

Comment: if it was linux dirsplit might work - its supposed to be standard on almost any box

Comment: Does the folder structure have to remain intact?

Comment: @Hello71: There should be a logical (sequential) split, not random. For example, 1st DVD should have 4.7 GB from the first folder, the 2nd one should have the remainings from the first folder, and complete the empty space with the second folder. Of course, that's for this particular example. A program with some flexible options would be great.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at [Burn to the Brim](http://bttb.sourceforge.net/). This program can regroup files so they will optimally fill CDs, DVDs or other media.

Comment: The program is outdated. The latest version was released on 10.10.2004. Howbeit I tried to install & run it, but it failed. I need a Windows 7 compatible program.

Comment: Mehper, Burn to the Brim works fine in Windows 7.

Comment: I've been able to install the program using WinXP compatibility mode (as nothing happened when I double clicked on the setup file). When I try to run the program, it gives a `wnaspi32.dll` error and does not start. I have Win 7 x64 and it does not work on my Sony Vaio.

Answer (score 2):

CDBurnerXP has a [disc-spanning option](http://cdburnerxp.se/help/data/disc-spanning). If you want to burn more data than a single disc can contain (for example, backups) you can use the disc spanning feature of CDBurnerXP to divide the data on multiple discs.

You can either save the results as ISO file or burn them to disc.

- Create a data compilation as usual
- When done, select *Disc ⇨ Disc spanning*

Answer (score 1):

This USE to be a common question on photo and video forums. Of course with hard drive prices these days, it actually makes more sense to do that. But I digress. . .

There was an older program called [SizeMe](http://lars.werner.no/?page_id=2).

It is going to be tough to find a program like this cause so few people use such an archaic method these days ...

Comment: SizeMe looks like what I need. I wish there was a decent alternative to it for Win 7.

Answer (score 0):

Inspired by [SizeMe](http://lars.werner.no/?page_id=2) in [surfasb's answer](https://superuser.com/questions/274811/allocate-split-folders-optimally-to-fit-dvds-windows-7/302912#302912), I searched for the alternatives and found two programs which sound useful.

- [DiscFit (Beta)](http://sourceforge.net/projects/discfit/)
- [Ignition](http://www.kcsoftwares.com/index.php?ignition)

Answer (score 0):

Use Ashampoo Burning Studio 6 Free. It does what you need, and can write on a variety of media, incl. Bluray.

[Ashampoo Burning Studio Free](https://www.ashampoo.com/en/usd/pde/7110/Burning_Software/Ashampoo-Burning-Studio-FREE)

Also, it is free of charge.